# Get lines that match with an array of values for a column - AWK

Tags: unix, awk, match

I would like to ask if there is any quick way, using awk, to get the values of the third column for each line that match to the first and second column with some values?

I have the situation where I have into an array variable the values to match for the second column of the file and a variable with the value to match for the first column.

So, I have the variables vals and chr:

```
chr="chr1"    
vals=($(seq 4 1 10))
echo ${vals[@]}
```

I would like to use them in a script like this :

```
res=$(awk '{if ($1=="'$chr'" && $2 in "'$vals[*]'") print $3} ' $depthFile)
```

Let's say I have this in my file:

```
chr1 5 length=35
chr1 6 length=35
chr1 7 length=35
chr1 8 length=35
chr1 9 length=76
chr1 10 length=35
chr1 11 length=35
chr1 12 length=35
chr1 13 length=35
chr1 14 length=76
```

And I have `6 7 8 9` in vals and chr = chr1.

I would expecting, using `echo ${res[@]}` to have:

```
length=35
length=35
length=35
length=76
```

So far I get this error. I know there is problem passing the vals array.

```
awk: cmd. line:1:  {if ($1=="chr1" && $2 in "4[*]") print $3} 
awk: cmd. line:1:                           ^ syntax error
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

if your values are a range instead of random numbers, you can code it more idiomatically

```
$ awk -v key="chr1" -v from=4 -v to=10 '$1==key && from<=$2 && $2<=to {print $3}' file

length=35
length=35
length=35
length=35
length=76
length=35
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Although, I tried it in my script file and it didn't well. I don't know the exactly reason. I suspect that it is because I am using variables for the numbers from and to. I have made some tests changing things to see what happen. In the case that I am only having the two conditions : `$1==key && $2<=to` works well, but when there are the three conditions or `$1==key && from<=$2 ` it doesn't. :(

Comment: But, using this `'($1==key && $2>=from ) {print $3; if($2==to) exit;}'` works fine !

Comment: Shouldn't `from<=$2 && $2<=to` be `from>=$2 && $2<=to` instead? @MarVi you should really **think** about the code you're using, don't just copy/paste it and then start trying random things to see if you can get the output you expect.

Comment: why? `[4,10]` is `$2>=4 && $2<=10`, i.e. include field 2 values from 4 to 10.